# Firebase OnAuthStateChanged for Phone Auth fires even for iOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, react-redux, react-native-firebase

I'm currently developing a mobile app where Firebase use for OTP service for both Android and iOS.Also have to mention I'm using react native with redux.

**Problem Background**

I'm using `react-native-firebase` library for firebase functions. As the documents say, for Android we can use `OnAuthStateChanged` to identify user has been signed in using google services. But for iOS, it is not possible to do that.

**Problem**

But for me, whenever I signed in with phone OTP, it automatically sign me in even with iOS device. So that is a problem.

**What I did**

Below is my code part for sign-in using phone.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).then(confirmResult =>{
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
                console.log('Auto signed in')
              })
        }
   })
}).catch(error => {console.log(error)})
```

So using `console.log`, i checked whether this actually works on iOS. And when I type my phone number and enter, I automatically gets logged in with `Auto Signed in` message in the debugger console. So this actually works with iOS. Also have to mention above code part is in, inside of redux action. All the dispatches (Redux thunk) happens if user is verified.

Then I needed to verify this works only when I receive the OTP. But even when I type a random phone number (Which is not use by current mobile), user sign-in without even receiving OTP.

**Real Problem**

This `OnAuthStateChange` triggers even without user receiving the OTP SMS. Which is a huge problem. What am I doing here wrong? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you considered using the verifyPhoneNumber flow on RNFB, might be more suited to your use case as it won't auto log the user in, see: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/phone-auth#verifyPhoneNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue with `onAuthStageChanged` function. However I guess that happens because you call `onAuthStageChanged` from inside of `signInWithPhoneNumber`.

Whenever you successfully sign-in with a given phone number,`onAuthStageChanged` function will be called. However frankly I don't have a good explanation on how this execution goes inside of `if(user)`. Anyhow I assume that because of you have already signed in with previous attempts to check the app.

So even without user ever being successfully signed-in, sign-in successful function kicks in because of `onAuthStageChanged` function call. You can check that using below code snippet. (I'm not quite familiar with thunk btw)

```
export const sampleFunc = () =>{
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            console.log('User signed in with just action call')
          })
        }
    })
     return(dispatch)=>{
       // Required dispatches.
    }
}
```

So calling above function from your class, you will see `User signed in with just action call` in console even without any auth stage changes.

Because of that, what I do is, just call `onAuthStateChanged` function from the ComponentDidMount in your class. So obviously user is not signed when component mounts. Then, from inside of `if(user)` call the required actions to save data and move to home screen after sign in successful.

So now, when you receive the Message on,

**iOS**

`onAuthStateChanged` will not be trigged as firebase says. So iOS should follow the basic OTP typing screen and validate from there.

**Android**

Using Google Play Services it will automatically recognize incoming message and will do necessary tasks to trig `onAuthStateChanged` function. Then because `ComponentDidMount` has already initialized `onAuthStateChanged`, this will be trigged and automatically sign user in.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into your suggestion and get back.

Comment: I did check what you suggested and it worked. Now what you said makes sense to me. Thanks alot.